How to set a state to a complex object in React?
I'm trying to set state for a team but I'm not able to do it.
I want to set individual state for each team without using any advance logic.
I tried many thing in code but nothing works. The state should be change for the team who's button is clicked and others remains same.

const PointsTable = () => {
    const [teams] = useState({
        CSK: { matchesPlayed: 0, wins: 0, loses: 0, points: 0 },
        MI: { matchesPlayed: 0, wins: 0, loses: 0, points: 0 },
        KKR: { matchesPlayed: 0, wins: 0, loses: 0, points: 0 },
        GT: { matchesPlayed: 0, wins: 0, loses: 0, points: 0 }
    });

    function input(teamName) {
        var teamName = document.querySelector('button').value;
        var matches = prompt("Enter total matches played: ");
        var win = prompt("Enter total matches won: ");
        var lose = matches - win;
        var point = win * 2;

        teams[teamName].matchesPlayed = matches;
        teams[teamName].wins = win;
        teams[teamName].loses = lose;
        teams[teamName].points = point;

    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>IPL Points Table</h2>
            <table border={1} cellPadding={20} cellSpacing={0}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Total Matches Played</th>
                        <th>Wins</th>
                        <th>Loses</th>
                        <th>Points</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>CSK</td>
                        <td>{teams.CSK.matchesPlayed}</td>
                        <td>{teams.CSK.wins}</td>
                        <td>{teams.CSK.loses}</td>
                        <td>{teams.CSK.points}</td>
                        <td><button value='CSK' onClick={() => input("CSK")}>CSK</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>MI</td>
                        <td>{teams.MI.matchesPlayed}</td>
                        <td>{teams.MI.wins}</td>
                        <td>{teams.MI.loses}</td>
                        <td>{teams.MI.points}</td>
                        <td><button value='MI' onClick={() => input("MI")}>MI</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>KKR</td>
                        <td>{teams.KKR.matchesPlayed}</td>
                        <td>{teams.KKR.wins}</td>
                        <td>{teams.KKR.loses}</td>
                        <td>{teams.KKR.points}</td>
                        <td><button value='KKR' onClick={() => input("KKR")}>KKR</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>GT</td>
                        <td>{teams.GT.matchesPlayed}</td>
                        <td>{teams.GT.wins}</td>
                        <td>{teams.GT.loses}</td>
                        <td>{teams.GT.points}</td>
                        <td><button value='GT' onClick={() => input("GT")}>GT</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PointsTable;

What can I try next?

You don't want to mutate your state (e.g., your teams object) directly. You need to immutably update the state via a setter. useState returns an array with two properties - the state, and a setter. You aren't using the 2nd property - you will need to. I suggest you read the react docs on this hook - https://react.dev/reference/react/useState - and also recommend going through the docs in general, their "learn" section is a good place to start - https://react.dev/learn

I know but is it necessary?

@MihirMakwana yes, it's the only way, for you are dealing with the state hook, not with a classic variable.

Yes, "A component’s props and state are immutable snapshots. Never mutate them directly. Instead, pass new props down, and use the setter function from useState."

You have significantly altered the code in your original question where previous answers may no longer be applicable. If you have a new question, please ask it as a new question, don't update the question here.

You shouldn't drastically change you question after receiving an answer. You should check, if it works and if yes, mark it as a correct answer.

If any edits were made to the code here after answers came in, please roll them back (I presently can't do it myself as there is a pending edit in the approval queue).

I have now rolled back to the last good question state, so the answers still make sense. I have tried to merge in an improvement from another editor.

Your usage of useState is incorrect. useState returns an array containing a state object and a "setter method" that updates the state object. This allows for updating a state object through the React rendering lifecycle. You cannot update a state variable directly, as you have tried.
Instead you should use the setter method, something like this:
const [teams, setTeams] = useState({
    CSK: { matchesPlayed: 0, wins: 0, loses: 0, points: 0 },
    MI: { matchesPlayed: 0, wins: 0, loses: 0, points: 0 },
    KKR: { matchesPlayed: 0, wins: 0, loses: 0, points: 0 },
    GT: { matchesPlayed: 0, wins: 0, loses: 0, points: 0 }
});

function handleInput(teamName) {
    const matches = prompt("Enter total matches played: ");
    const win = prompt("Enter total matches won: ");
    const lose = matches - win;
    const point = win * 2;

    setTeams(prevTeams => ({
        ...prevTeams,
        [teamName]: {
            matchesPlayed: matches,
            wins: win,
            loses: lose,
            points: point
        }
    }));
}

The JSX HTML would look like this:
return (
    <div>
        <h2>IPL Points Table</h2>
        <table border={1} cellPadding={20} cellSpacing={0}>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Total Matches Played</th>
                    <th>Wins</th>
                    <th>Loses</th>
                    <th>Points</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>CSK</td>
                    <td>{teams.CSK.matchesPlayed}</td>
                    <td>{teams.CSK.wins}</td>
                    <td>{teams.CSK.loses}</td>
                    <td>{teams.CSK.points}</td>
                    <td><button onClick={() => handleInput("CSK")}>CSK</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>MI</td>
                    <td>{teams.MI.matchesPlayed}</td>
                    <td>{teams.MI.wins}</td>
                    <td>{teams.MI.loses}</td>
                    <td>{teams.MI.points}</td>
                    <td><button onClick={() => handleInput("MI")}>MI</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>KKR</td>
                    <td>{teams.KKR.matchesPlayed}</td>
                    <td>{teams.KKR.wins}</td>
                    <td>{teams.KKR.loses}</td>
                    <td>{teams.KKR.points}</td>
                    <td><button onClick={() => handleInput("KKR")}>KKR</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>GT</td>
                    <td>{teams.GT.matchesPlayed}</td>
                    <td>{teams.GT.wins}</td>
                    <td>{teams.GT.loses}</td>
                    <td>{teams.GT.points}</td>
                    <td><button onClick={() => handleInput("GT")}>GT</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
);

Additionally, I wouldn't use prompt here to update the values, but instead I'd create some React component or HTML input that handles the new data, perhaps as Form Fields or within a Modal.

Your useState() hook usage is wrong.
You should initialise it like this:
 const [teams, setTeams] = useState({ 
         // stays the same
    });

Then you use setTeams to change the value of teams.

Here is the entire working code with some improvements. I believe the other comments have already explained the issues with this.
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react'

export function App(props) {
  const [teams, setTeams] = useState({
    CSK: { matchesPlayed: 0, wins: 0, loses: 0, points: 0 },
    MI: { matchesPlayed: 0, wins: 0, loses: 0, points: 0 },
    KKR: { matchesPlayed: 0, wins: 0, loses: 0, points: 0 },
    GT: { matchesPlayed: 0, wins: 0, loses: 0, points: 0 }
  });

  function input(teamName) {
    var matches = +prompt("Enter total matches played: ");
    var win = +prompt("Enter total matches won: ");
    var lose = matches - win;
    var point = win * 2;
    console.log(teamName, matches, win, lose, point)

    let newTeams = {...teams}

    newTeams[teamName].matchesPlayed = matches;
    newTeams[teamName].wins = win;
    newTeams[teamName].loses = lose;
    newTeams[teamName].points = point;

    setTeams(newTeams)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>IPL Points Table</h2>
      <table border={1} cellPadding={20} cellSpacing={0}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Total Matches Played</th>
            <th>Wins</th>
            <th>Loses</th>
            <th>Points</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            Object.keys(teams).map((key) => {
              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{key}</td>
                  <td>{teams[key].matchesPlayed}</td>
                  <td>{teams[key].wins}</td>
                  <td>{teams[key].loses}</td>
                  <td>{teams[key].points}</td>
                  <td><button onClick={() => input(key)}>{key}</button></td>
                </tr>
              )
            })
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

